# Fixed setting the date or time from today in Swift/UIKit

Tags: ios, swift, date, datetime, uikit

I have an app I'm working on that when it is out of working hours (corporate app) that the app becomes inactive or stops the `Timer` network calls.

However I am finding it difficult to set the start and end times of operation.

As a pseudo code:

```swift
// get current hour
let calendar = Calendar.current
let dateComponents = calendar.dateComponents(in: TimeZone.current, from: date)
guard let currentHour   = dateComponents.hour else { return }

// set the date format
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss-1000"

// check if it is before 0800 or after 1800
if( currentHour < 8 || currentHour > 18 ) {

  // out of hours
  if( currentHour < 8 ) {
    // -- set start time to today 0800 (1)
    // -- set end time to today 1800
  }

  if( currentHour > 18 ) {
    // -- set start time to tomorrow 0800
    // -- set end time to tomorrow 1800
  }

} else {

  // -- set start time to now
  // -- set end time to 1800

}
```

But is there a simple way for (1) saying get today date, plus one day, and set the time to 0800?

Everything I read seems to be converting from Date to String or vice-versa.

But I seem to fall short on finding anything on fixed times or dates.

Is this something that's possible or easy to set up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just extend Date by these two functions and you have all the functionality you need:

```
extension Date {
    
    public func plusOneDay() -> Date {
        return self.advanced(by: 24 * 60 * 60)
    }
    
    public func setHour(_ hour: Int) -> Date? {
        let calendar: Calendar = Calendar.current
        let dateComponents: DateComponents = calendar.dateComponents(in: TimeZone.current, from: self)
        guard let year: Int = dateComponents.year else { return nil }
        guard let month: Int = dateComponents.month else { return nil }
        guard let day: Int = dateComponents.day else { return nil }
        let componentsAtChangedTime: DateComponents = DateComponents(calendar: nil, timeZone: TimeZone.current, era: nil, year: year, month: month, day: day, hour: hour, minute: nil, second: nil, nanosecond: nil, weekday: nil, weekdayOrdinal: nil, quarter: nil, weekOfMonth: nil, weekOfYear: nil, yearForWeekOfYear: nil)
        return calendar.date(from: componentsAtChangedTime)
    }
    
}
```

If you want more precise handling, like minute and second defining you can add this to the function.
Now all you need to do is:

```
let now: Date = Date()
let todayAt8: Date = now.setHour(8)!
let tomorowAt8: Date = todayAt8.plusOneDay()
```

Edit: with this solution you can also get rid of the currentHour, so you don't need to get it and have less code in your way:

```
let startTime: Date
let endTime: Date
// compare Date's directly
if now < todayAt8 || now > todayAt18 {
    if now < todayAt8 {
        // -- set start time to today 0800 (1)
        startTime = todayAt8
        // -- set end time to today 1800
        endTime = todayAt18
    } else /*if now > todayAt18*/ { // check not needed since it is only other case
        // -- set start time to tomorrow 0800
        startTime = tomorowAt8
        // -- set end time to tomorrow 1800
        endTime = tomorowAt18
    }
} else {
    // -- set start time to now
    startTime = now
    // -- set end time to 1800
    endTime = todayAt18
}
```

Comment: I added a suggestion for a change of the code, that enables you to remove everything that is needed to get currentHour from the Date().

Comment: haha! thank you @Jelumar - I just reopened the project for the day and saw the edit. saves a bit of extra logic